# Is there a way from me to load code from another file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a text based python game at the moment. And i'm trying to make a save function so that you can continiue from where you were last time you played. The way i have set it up is that different choises i make ingame is saved to an external file. Is there a way i could make it read that file and having it say for example " story_beginning_eatbreakfeast() " and the main file then calling that function?

```
def story_beginning_eatbreakfeast():
    os.system("cls")
    f = open("save.py", "w")
    global Color
    global Gender
    global Weight
    global Food_eaten
    f.write("Color = " + str(Color) + "\n")
    f.write("Gender = " + str(Gender) + "\n")
    f.write("Weight = " + str(Weight) + "\n")
    f.write("Food_eaten = " + str(Food_eaten) + "\n")
    f.write("story_beginning_eatbreakfeast()" + "\n")
```

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is hard to understand

Comment: I would try something like this: start the main program, try to find the "save file" previous created, and find the name of the "restarting point" function in it. Then if your functions are in a class, you can define the start by `start = getattr(self, "story_beginning_eatbreakfast")` and start whenever you want by calling `start()`. Don't forget about a *default value* if the save file does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

The most common way (that I've seen or used, anyway) is to use the json module to encode and write out, then read later and decode, your state data structure, but since all of your information is in discrete globals, that won't work for you. I'd advise that you gather your data into a single dictionary (or class, if that makes any sense to you) so that you can do this. That way, you can deal with saving and restoring state without the code having to know about every little detail about your data.
It's clear that you're just starting out. Try to find a better book on programming. Good practice is to make things like saving state as simple as possible, which means you don't have to rewrite them when (not if) you change your data.